# Add -1 day to DBDatetime with a specific timestamp in php

Tags: php, date

lets assume that NOW is 2021-09-15 (DBDatetime format). I would like to add to that existing date -1 day and set time to be at 10:00 AM, so:

Initial date would be: 2021-09-15
Expired date would be: 2021-09-16 10:00 AM

The reason for that is I would like to get videos (on my newbie site) even after their airing time exired. So lets say expiring time is set to initial date and i want to have that till 21-09-16 10:00 AM is up.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very easy with [DateTime::modify](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.modify.php).

```
$basisDate = '2021-09-15';  //or 'today' for the current day

$date = date_create($basisDate)->modify('+1 Day 10:00');

//test output
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i");  //2021-09-16 10:00
```

Another variant, not so tricky and easier to understand:

```
$date = date_create($basisDate)
  ->modify('+1 Day')
  ->setTime(10,0)
;
```